# Aceptar solo formatos pdf, no sobreescribir y al guardar que se almacene en una carpeta diferente por día

Tags: php

Tengo este pedazo de codigo php donde desde un form elijo un archivo pdf necesito ayuda para que al guardar se almacene en una carpeta adentro de 'archivos/' y que por dia conforme se ingresan archivos se genere una carpeta nueva y en caso de que ya exista el archivo no permita sobreescribirlo y que solo acepte pdf.

```html
<?php
$directorio = 'archivos/';
$subir_archivo = $directorio.basename($_FILES['subir_archivo']['name']);
echo "<div>";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['subir_archivo']['tmp_name'], $subir_archivo)) {
      echo "<div class='modal fade' id='mostrarmodal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='basicModal' aria-hidden='true'>
          <div class='modal-dialog'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
              <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                <center>  <h3>ARCHIVO SUBIDO CORRECTAMENTE</h3> </center>
              </div>
              <div class='modal-body'>
                <center> <a class='btn btn-primary' href='subirpdf.php'>ACEPTAR</a> </center>   
              </div>
              <div class='modal-footer'></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>";
    } else {
       echo "<div class='modal fade' id='mostrarmodal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='basicModal' aria-hidden='true'>
          <div class='modal-dialog'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
              <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                <center>  <h3>NO SE PUDO SUBIR EL ARCHIVO</h3> </center>
              </div>
              <div class='modal-body'>
                <center> <a class='btn btn-primary' href='subirpdf.php'>ACEPTAR</a> </center>   
              </div>
              <div class='modal-footer'></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una validacion `if(is_readable($file))` antes de el upload ya que esta funcion valida que exista y que sea legible!
Y cambiar

```
$subir_archivo = $directorio.basename(date("Ymd"); move_uploaded_file($_FILES['subir_archivo']['tmp_name'], $subir_archivo)
```

Para que el archivo se llame como el dia ejemplo:
20190108.txt
Y solo validas `if(is_readable($subir_archivo))` ante todo!